# Check if string starts with number

Tags: ruby

How can I check if my string starts with a number?

I'm trying to make this work by using the starts_with ruby method with no luck:

```
<% if line.start_with?("ANY NUMBER") %>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try with regex: `line.start_with?(/[0-9]/)`

Comment: "no luck" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Regular Expressions, `\A` means start of string, and `\d` means any digit. So this could work for you:

```
if line.match?(/\A\d/)
```

Comment: Using ruby DSL looks like: `Integer(line[0])` that raises an `ArgumentError` or you can use `line[0].to_i` but it returns `0` if the value is not an Integer, so if you convert a `0` or a String, you can get a false positive...